# Proving the Determinant is the unique multilinear, alternating map (uniqueness proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am studying an introduction to differential forms, where an m-form on $T_pR^n$ is a function $\omega$ from $T_pR^n$ to $R$ such that $\omega$ is multilinear and alternating.

I understand how to show the determinant is a multilinear and alternating map, but how would one show the determinant is the unique multilinear and alternating map? (i.e. so these two algebraic conditions force $\omega$ to act as a determinant).

Thank you for any ideas/help!

NOTE: With the added property that $det(I)=1$

Comment: That's not true. You also need to add the condition that the determinant of the identity matrix is 1.

Comment: Okay. So then what is the proof with that condition too...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants Enjoy (if a matrix argument satisfies you)

Comment: @FShrike Thank you

Comment: Have you seen the proof that $\dim \Lambda^k(V) = \binom{\dim V}k$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I covered the proof last week.

Comment: So the fact that that dimension is $1$ when $k=\dim V$ shows it more abstractly.